# Google oAuth example

Tags: oauth

I'm looking for a worked example of how to call into Googles oAuth service with a view to simply uploading a txt file.  On googles docs I have the followed the example
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

but it won't compile .... CalendarScopes.CALENDAR  is the problem and I can't see what Jar contains this class.   I imported every Jar in the google-oauth-java-client-1.12.0-beta download  (Also every jar in google-api-java-client-1.12.0-beta )  I dobn't understand the diff between these but that is for another day.

Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: What is the error/stack trace the class gives you in the jar?

Comment: Class not found ,  won't compile for me

Answer (score 0):

CalendarScopes.CALENDAR that you mentioned is not a part of a jar file but a scope for [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) provided by Google. For a sample to show how to implement that, here is [one](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate).

In the meanwhile, I would also suggest going over the following links to develop an understanding of the OAuth and how to use it with the different APIs.

1. [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) - This is very helpful when trying to learn about different API and permissions relating to those.
2. [OpenID Connect Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect)

Hope this helps.